# Can we flush the values in an array, taking the values from a for loop in shell

Tags: arrays, shell, if-statement, for-loop

I have a requirement where in I am running a for loop for 1440 times, and I want to take the odd numbers out, fill the first six enteries in an array, use them in a command, and then re flush the array with the next 6 values.

eg.

```
for (( i=1;i<1441;i++))
do

 a=`expr $i % 2` 
 if [[ $a -ne 0 ]]
 then
 array[a]=((val1  val2 val3 val4 val5 val6))
 echo "The set 1 contains num1 num3 num5 num7 num9 num11"
done >> This should flush the values again with next set  till 1440.
```

Can this be done. Or is this logic invalid?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @devnull : I want to implement a logic, where I take odd values from a set of numbers, put first six of them on to a array, use those six numbers from the array, to a single line, and then go back to take the next six values and so on.

Comment: How are you using the array? It appears that each element of `array` (which, by the way, you only seem to use once) is itself an array of 6 values (whose source is unclear). `bash` does not easily support nested arrays, as they are intended as a secondary source of quoting, not as a building block for complex data structure.

Comment: 'Tis odd that you'd use the `((...))` for loop notation but not use `a=$(($i % 2))` or thereabouts instead of `expr`.  However, that's tangential to your question — which is still not clear.  Your code is missing a `fi` and doesn't use the array, so it really isn't clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a loop that will maintain a queue of length 6:

```
last6=(0 1 3 5 7 9)        # a 6-element array

# loop over odd numbers
for ((i=11; i<=1440; i+=2)); do 
    last6=("${last6[@]:1:5}" $i)  # discard the first element and add a new elem
    echo "${last6[*]}"
done
```

```
1 3 5 7 9 11
3 5 7 9 11 13
5 7 9 11 13 15
7 9 11 13 15 17
...
1425 1427 1429 1431 1433 1435
1427 1429 1431 1433 1435 1437
1429 1431 1433 1435 1437 1439
```